# Where does the minus sign go when deriving the Stefan-Boltzmann Constant?

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, integration, wavelength

When deriving the stefan boltzmann law from planks law. You may make a substitution (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan2.html). This substitution will lead to a stray minus sign in the equation. The rest of the derivation seems to just ignore the minus sign. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you substitute

$$x=\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}$$

the limits of the integral also get reversed since

$$x=0\iff \lambda\to \infty\quad\rm{and}\quad x\to \infty \iff\lambda=0$$

Thus removing/cancelling the minus sign is completely justified.